# passing variables from matlab to c# application

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am trying to pass a cell array (tried a table as well) from Matlab to my C# application. How do I do this?

I can pass a string to my c# application from Matlab but can't seem to pass a vector of strings or a cell array (which contains dates & text)

**Matlab Code**

```
DllPath = 'C:\MyPath\MyLibrary.dll';
ass = NET.addAssembly(DllPath);
myCls = AssName.ClassName;
colName = [{'abc'}; {'des'}];
myCls.Foo('sddsdd', colName);
```

The function below is not useful at the moment I'm just using it to play around with. I can read the tableName variable fine & I can cast the colName variable to a string[].

**C#**

```
    public int Foo(string tableName, object colName)
    {
        string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)colName).Cast<object>()
                             .Select(x => x.ToString())
                             .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(tableName);
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);

        return arr.Length;
    }
```

Comment: You can't pass strings.  You need to pass an array of byte[] and terminate data with a '\0'.

Comment: @jdweng the code above allows me to pass strings or are you saying in the background the string is being passed an array of bytes?

Comment: Try this : byte[] message = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");